# Android Volley で送信した JSON データを、 Python(cgi) で受け取るには

Tags: android, python, json, android-volley

Android のライブラリ Volley で JSON を POSTで送った後、Pythonで取り出せません。

#### クライアント側 (Android )

```java
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,jsonData,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

#### サーバ側 (Python)

```python
import json
import sys
import cgi

print "Content-Type: application/json\n"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form

myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
print myjson
```

#### 結果

```
FieldStorage(None, None, '{"key":"value"}')
```

#### エラーログ

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 20, in <module>
    myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

`curl` で　`-d "{'key':'value'}"` で渡しても同じでした。

データの送信自体はできているようなのですが、自由に使えるデータとして変数に格納するなど、取り出す方法がわかりません。回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Androidからの受け渡し部分は省略して、 `curl -d`で実行した場合を仮定します。

`cgi.FieldStorage`を使用すると、`sys.stdin`を読み込んでしまっているので、`json.load(sys.stdin)`で取り出せるのは空文字列になります。

`curl -d`の引数が間違っていませんか？`"{'key':'value'}"`ではなく、`'{"key":"value"}'`として下さい。

```
呼び出し:
$ curl -d '{"key":"value"}' "http://example.com/execute.py"

受け取り:
# FieldStorageは削除して
print json.load(sys.stdin)
```

Answer (score 1):

`myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)`
を
`myjson = json.loads(sys.stdin)`
にした場合はどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`TypeError: expected string or buffer`となってできませんでした。